# Problema con CloudFirestore (AndroidStudio - Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, lista, google-cloud-firestore

estoy realizando una app en Android con Java, y estoy subiendo una lista de imágenes que el usuario seleccione al Storage, de acuerdo a esto, estoy sacando las Urls de estas mismas para mandarlos a Cloud Storage para luego extraerlas y usarlas, el problema es que solo se muestra una sola URL de una foto y no la de las demas fotos.

[image: Subiendo 3 fotos al storage]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en las fotos, el usuario agrego 3 fotos al storage, pero en la base de datos solo se muestra una URL, y quisiera que en el documento de cada usuario se agreguen los links y no solo un link, así como en la segunda foto.

**Este es el código donde subo las fotos al Storage y obtengo los links:**

```
       //Verificamos si el usuario subio una foto a la lista
    if (listaImages != null) {

        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Publicando");
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();

        for (int i = 0; i < listaImages.size(); i++) {
            Uri pruebaUri = listaImages.get(i);
            final StorageReference prueba = storageRef.child("Fotos").child(pruebaUri.getLastPathSegment());
            prueba.putFile(pruebaUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    prueba.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            url = String.valueOf(uri);
                            SubirDB(url);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**Este es el método donde recibo las URLS y lo subo a la base de datos:**

```
private void SubirDB(String url) {

    //Obteniendo los campos de texto
    String titulo = tituloNoticias.getText().toString();
    String texto = textoNoticias.getText().toString();

    HashMap<String, String> urls = new HashMap<>();
    urls.put("links: ", url);
    Toast.makeText(Formulario.this, " " + urls, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    //Añadiendo los datos a la CloudFirestore
    datos.put("Título", titulo);
    datos.put("Texto", texto);
    datos.put("Fotos", urls);

    db.collection("Users").document(" UsuarioAnónimo")
            .set(datos);
}
```

Utilice ese Toast para ver si realmente recibía las URLS.

Espero me puedan ayudar con esto, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Pregunta: ¿En `SubirDB()` puedes ver todas las URLs? Otra cosa muy rara es que el nodo en Firestore se llama `Fotos` y luego en el `HashMap` creas un elemento llamado `links` ¿? Lo correcto es que el nodo (en este caso `Fotos`) sea del tipo `Map` en Firestore y que le pases un array con las URLs.

Comment: Sí, por eso le puse el Toast para ver si recibía y veía las URLs.
Gracias por la ayuda, lo implemente como decías de pasarlo como un array y me salio perfectamente. De nuevo muchas gracias.